# How to make a flashable zip of ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development, porting-ubuntu-touch

I've followed the proceedure in
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/
to make a ubuntu build for my device.
Now I want to try this rom in my mobile.
I want to create a flashable zip just like cyanogenmod's zips.
How to do that?

Comment: I think this may be an Android based question, you don't give a device but `flashable zips` are for Android, the guide you link shows you how to install the rom on a phone, under the `Building` section, you should ask at the xda forum page for your device or http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This procedure will vary when we are doing for ubuntu touch. It will be useful for other ubuntu-touch users also. I think this is the right place for the question